# Form_for - redirect with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, form-for

I use `form_for(@user)` in a view `settings#info` :

```
# ./views/settings/info.html.erb

<%= form_for(@user) do |f|  %>

    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li>* <%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
...
<% end %>


# ./controllers/users_controller.rb

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params["user"])
        ....
    else
      render template: 'settings/info'
    end

  end
```

Everything is working great, errors are shown if there are some. But, because I pass some variables in `info` action of settings_controllers.rb, I need to change it to a redirect (with errors). How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the case of a redirect i usually use the rails `flash` object and add the errors directly.

```
flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages.join(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized I can't get errors one by one. Is there a way to do that ?